# how to get audio file from a WMV video?

Tags: audio, mp3, wav, wmv

I have a WMV file. I want a WAV or MP3 of its audio. Is this possible without some dubious shareware?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is very straightforward with FFMPEG.  See http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/#basicaudio

You can do the same thing with VLC.  http://www.videolan.org/vlc/